# How to get latest RMP data?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

In Realm Browser and in my App I can watch how rows get deleted, modified and created when I log in with a Sync User, like it is getting synced slowly, when I login my app I would like to know when this sync ends, or better, get only the latest data at once and not the whole history of it.

I don't know if is a setting in Realm Object Server (Ubuntu) or in my App (iOS Swift)

Answer (score 0):

Realm Mobile Platform syncs your data automatically in background, it allows you to work with the Realm url the same way you work with the local one.

So you can just use [any type of Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) to handle any data changes.

Comment: Yeah but most of times it takes a real lot of time to finish the sync when iPad 1 App has been closed for a few hour and iPad 2 do a couple of actions (delete, add, update, objects).

I sit and watch how objects get created, deleted again, creaed, updates like if I was seeing a timeline

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to handle download progress right now, but it's a something we're working on.